# How to delete rows in CSV-Output in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following problem: When I run my program in the output CSV are some columns which i dont want to have in my output csv.

```
googlenews = GoogleNews()
googlenews.set_encode('utf_8')
googlenews.get_news('Trump')

keys = googlenews.results()[0].keys()

with open('Outputfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    alpha = csv.DictWriter(file, keys)
    alpha.writeheader()
    alpha.writerows(googlenews.results())
```

Comment: When you say "rows like desc, datetime, img and media", do you really mean "columns like desc, datetime, img and media"?

Comment: Have you tried quoting your request, as in `googlenews.get_news('"Air Wings"')`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sure, I ment columns not rows :D I am sorry. 
Your quotoing style fixed my second problem :) Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what `GoogleNews().results` returns.  If it is a list of dictionaries, then you just need to enumerate through the set, creating a new list with dictionaries that only have the columns you want.

Comment: Please leave the code in the question. It helps to understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking too hard.  All I mean is something like this:

```
newlist = []
for row in googlenews.results():
    newlist.append( { 'title': row['title'], 'date': row['date' } )

with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, newlist[0].keys())
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(newlist)
```

Comment: Do you probably know how to run the code for more than one keyword?
For example if I want to search for "London" and "New York". Is there any possibility to get the news for these topics in one CSV which containt two sheets? One with News for London and the other one with News for New York

Comment: CSV files do not contain "sheets".  "Sheets" are an Excel concept that only applies to Excel-formatted files.  If you really want to go through the trouble, you can use `openpyxl` or `xlswriter` to write XLSX files directly, but in my opinion it's not worth the trouble.  You can open two CSV files in Excel and use cut and paste to combine them.